# Cannot access to changed property

Tags: php

I've created a class called `Boot`, inside this I've a method that change the path of a file, so the user can call it to set a custom path, something like this:

```
class Boot
{
    private static $_filePath = 'directory/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        require 'system.php';
    }

    public function init()
    {
         new System();
    } 

    public function setFilePath($newDir)
    {
        $this->_filePath = $newDir;
    }

    public static function getFilePath()
    {
        return self::_filePath;
    }
}
```

so in my `index.php` file:

```
require 'boot.php';

$b = new Boot();
$b->setFilePath('directories/');
$b->init();
```

Now in the system class I call something like this:

```
echo Boot::getFilePath();
```

and should be displayed `directories/` but I see again the default value: `directory`.

Now I though that this issue is related to the `static` field, but how can I access to the changed value so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class variables defined with and without `static` are **different** variables.

One solution is to remove `static` from variable declaration and change `getPath` code, as you already have instance of `Boot` defined witn `new`:

```
class Boot
{
    private $_filePath = 'directory/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        require 'system.php';
    }

    public function init()
    {
         new System();
    } 

    public function setFilePath($newDir)
    {
        $this->_filePath = $newDir;
    }

    public function getFilePath()
    {
        return $this->_filePath;
    }
}
```

And call `getFilePath()` as

```
echo $b->getFilePath();
```

Another solution is to change both `setFilePath` and `getFilePath`:

```
public function setFilePath($newDir)
{
    // set STATIC variable
    self::$_filePath = $newDir;
}

public static function getFilePath()
{
    // get STATIC variable
    return self::$_filePath;
}
```

But in the end it's a bad approach because you will make mistakes deciding whether you need to access a `static variable` or a `property of an object`.

So it's better to make a decision - either you have an instance of `Boot` and get properties of it or you have only static methods in a class and forget about `Boot` instance.

Comment: nope, I doesn't have any instance of `Boot` in `System`. I've the instance of `Boot` in my `index.php` file, but I need to access to the path of `$_filePath` inside `boot` from my class `system` that's declared inside `boot`. I don't know if is more clear now.

Comment: Pass `$b` as argument to `System` constructor.

Comment: this is the only solution for fix the problem?

Comment: Nice solution, your update seems good in my case, 'cause I change the value only one time. Thanks for this :)